# How do I call a PHP function in a separate file using Ajax but no jQuery?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a page where the user can create child jobs in the parent job by clicking an Add New button and causing a new row to appear which they then fill in and save. The row has an autogenerated reference number, which is obtained by calling a PHP script in another file.

The problem is that each new row has the same reference number, so I need a way to make sure that number is unique. My thought was to send in a second parameter to the function of the current reference number to see if it's the same as the current number and, if so, generate a different number. My thought was to use Ajax.

I tried Ajax, but it is not displaying anything in the console (to test that it's working). The page uses MooTools, so I can't use jQuery.  This is my first attempt at Ajax.

This is part of the template:

```
<script id="connectedjobtemplate" type="text/template">
    <tr id="childjobrow3" class="odd" data-row-id="3">
        <td>
            <input data-row-id="3" id="reference[3]" name="childjobid[3][reference]" value="<%= ref %>" class="ref" size="14" style="background-color: transparent; border: none;" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</script>
```

This checks for a click on the Add New button and calls the function to add a new row:

```
$(document.body).addEvent('click:relay(#add-new-row)', function (e, el) {
                try{
                    e.preventDefault();
                    addChildJobRow();
                }catch(e){
                    .
                }
            });
```

This is the addChildJobRow function:

```
function addChildJobRow() {
                try {
                    lastrow++;
                    var refNum;
                    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
                        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                            console.log(this.responseText);
                            refNum = this.responseText;
                        }
                    };
                    xhr.open('GET', '<?php echo $this->MJob->getNewJobRef(232); ?>', true);
                    xhr.onload = function() {
                        console.log('Test');
                    };
                    xhr.send();
                    //refNum = '<?php echo $this->MJob->getNewJobRef(232); ?>';
                    Elements.from(connectedjobtemplate({
                        rownum: lastrow,
                        cl: cl,
                        ref: refNum,
                        nysid: '',
                        dinNum: '',
                        warrantNum: ''
                    })).inject($('newChildJobTable'));
                } catch (e) {
                    .
                }
            }
```

Nothing appears in the console. I am thinking that the problem might be the PHP being sent in as the url in the xhr.open line, but don't know enough Ajax to know if that's the problem or not.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Is the request being sent? If so, does the response show anything?

Comment: I don't know if the request is being sent. The console shows nothing. I have never used Ajax before, so please excuse my ignorance.

Comment: Check the network tab in the console and see if your request shows up when the AJAX request is sent.

Comment: @Script47, yes, it is being sent.

Comment: I'm a little confused by this question. For one, your title says you want to do it without jQuery, but then present a snippet which uses jQuery (and the question doesn't appear to be "how do I translate this to vanilla JS"). More importantly though, right at the start you say "The problem is that each new row has the same reference number," - this suggests to me that the real way to fix this is to go back here and make sure each row has a unique number in the first place.

Comment: @RobinZigmond, the page uses MooTools. Which line(s) would be jQuery? I am trying to get the unique reference number before it is sent to the template being generated. Is there a better place to do that?

Comment: @RivaPortman the `$` function used in your second snippet looks like jQuery to me - but it's possible I've misunderstood. I just looked up MooTools (which I've never heard of) and it looks similar to jQuery but uses `$$` instead of `$`. Perhaps your script has renamed it though?

Comment: regarding "is there a better place to do that", I don't understand what your page really does and the functionality you are after, but you said "The row has an autogenerated reference number, which is obtained by calling a PHP script in another file." - and then go on to mention that this returns the same reference number for new rows. I am simply suggesting that it would be better to alter this PHP script (which you don't show) so that the reference numbers were all unique.

Comment: @RobinZigmond, from what I understand, the single dollar sign is for one element and the two dollars signs are to access multiple elements. I had never heard of MooTools before I got this job either, but they use it here and it conflicts with jQuery.

Comment: That was my first idea, but I need a way to pass the current reference number back to the script to check it against the number being generated. Would it help if I posted the PHP script?

Comment: You need to pass an existing URI towards `xhr.open('GET', validUriHere);`...

Comment: @DarkBee, would that be `'MJob/getNewJobRef(232)'`?

Comment: `http//www.example.com/location/to/ajax/script.php`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After speaking to my boss, he wants me to not use Ajax and call the PHP function, just read the number of the parent job and increment each of the child jobs by 1 using JavaScript.

Thank you to those who responded.